# combining the text files in to one text file

Tags: linux, shell

i have a requirement like the following.
i am using linux

i have a set of text files like `text1.txt ,text2.txt, text3.txt`. 
now i am combining into one final text file.

**text1.txt**

```
1    
NULL    
NULL    
4
```

**text2.txt**

```
1    
2    
NULL    
4
```

**text3.txt**

```
a    
b    
c    
d
```

i am using the following command :

```
paste -d ' ' text1.txt text2.txt text3.txt  >> text4.txt
```

i am getting the :

**text4.txt**

```
1 1 a   
2 b    
c  
4 4 d
```

but i want the output like the following

**text4.txt**

```
1 1 a
NULL 2 b
NULL NULL c
4 4 d
```

NOTE :- NULL means space

i am passing this text4 to another loop as a input so here there i am reading the variable by positionl

thanks in advance

Comment: `paste -d' ' f1 f2 f3` works fine for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that you want TABs separating your records in `file4.txt`... what about this?

```
NLINES=$(wc -l file1.txt | awk '{print $1}')
rm -f file4.txt
for i in $(seq 1 $NLINES); do
  rec1=$(sed -n "$i p" file1.txt)
  rec2=$(sed -n "$i p" file2.txt)
  rec3=$(sed -n "$i p" file3.txt)
  echo -e "$rec1\t$rec2\t$rec3" >> file4.txt
done
```

But actually paste, without "-d ' '" gave the same exact result!

Comment: i am getting unexcepted syntax at the end of the line 9

Comment: paste "-d ' '" is giving my requirement . but i have to cut the first position from all the text files .

Comment: once i got the final text file i am passing that text file to the while loop. in the while loop i am using the variable in to my program

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve same with AWK command

```
awk '{a[FNR]=a[FNR]$0" "}END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)print a[i]}' text1.txt text2.txt text3.txt >> text4.txt
```